# Excel - Assign vlookup value based on date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking for either an index and match formula or Vlookup formula to return only the providers name based on a date range. For example, I need the provider's name for the ID's DOS that falls within the provider's start date and end date range. Even if the provider's end date is blank/NULL.

The table on the left is missing the provider assigned to that Member's ID. The DOS represents the date of service a member received a service.

The table on the right is the history of a member's providers.  For example, ID 1234 was assigned to Bob for during the date range 1/1/2016 (start date) to 2/13/2016 (End date).

The table on the left is when the member received a service. For instance, Member ID 1234 had a Date of Service (DOS) on  7/2/2016. The provider, Alan, is what I need returned since he was the provider assigned to that member (ID) during that DOS.  Alan's start date: 2/14/2016 And End Date: 9/30/2016. So Alan should be returned as the provider the Member ID 1234 with DOS of 7/2/2016.

I am working with Excel 2010.

[image: Reference]

Comment: In the green section which columns are you providing and which needs to be a formula? If I understand right you are providing Provider and ID and the formula just returns DOS. Also in this sample data you have multiple providers with the same ID is this something that happens in the real data as well or no?

Comment: Can you explain little more, how you are detecting falls?

Comment: I added more details and clearer explanation in both my post and screenshot. Let me know if that helps clarify what it is I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula at `A2` then copy/paste it all the way down

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1,IF((H:H<=C2)*OR(I:I>=C2,ISBLANK(I:I))*(G:G=B2),1)))  Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Comment: Does this only work if the table on the right is sorted by ID ASC, Provider start Date ASC, and Provider End Date ASC? Because it seems to work if that is the case in this example. I can always sort the data that way.

 But if I change the sorting orders to just sort by provider start date to newest to oldest it does not work properly. It assigns bob to ID 1234.

Comment: No it should work whatever the order of the data, provided that the data remains consistent. You should make sure that when sorting you dont change the data (are you sorting each column alone)? The only thing to know is that it returns the first match, so if there are more than one record that matches the criteria, the result may change but the new resullt should be correct as well.